Lost my job after working 19 months on blue card taking financial help from Agentur fur arbeit would be effect on future PR?
I'm a non EU citizen. Currently I have a German Blue Card residence permit. I'm planning to apply for a permanent residence (after 21 months with B1 German knowledge proof). The problem now is that i have lost my job and I worked 19 months without gap. So now if go to Agentur für Arbeit to take financial help it would be any problem to take Permanent Residency in future?

Is your question what happens when you find another job and when you will then be able to apply for permanent residence? As you may know, the requirement is 21 months of work and contribution to the insurance system, not 21 months of residence. So the time after you lost your job won't count even if you don't claim your unemployment benefits. And it's also required to be employed in a job fulfilling the blue card requirements to apply so it wouldn't be possible to do it even if you had already worked 21 months.

In other words, none of this should impact your decision to go to the Agentur für Arbeit, claim the benefits you are owed, and rely on these benefits to make the best use of the 6 months you have to find another job.
